# Unable to Catch the FaultException thrown by WCF Service in SilverLight client Application

Tags: wcf, silverlight, c#-4.0, faultexception

I am Calling a WCF Service Method from my Silverlight Application. Wcf Service is returning a Fault Exception on Failure. I am able to throw the fault exception from my WCF Service. But it is not receiving to my Silverlight Application(.xaml.cs). Instead I am getting an exception  "Communication Exception was unhandled by User, the remote server returned an Error:NotFound"
in References.cs file(AutoGenerated File)

I am calling the WCF Service Method in my .Xaml.cs file like below

```
      private void btnExecuteQuery_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
         try
           {
            objService.GetDataTableDataAsync(_DATABASENAME, strQuery);
           objService.GetDataTableDataCompleted += new    EventHandler<GetDataTableDataCompletedEventArgs>(objService_GetDataTableDataCompleted);

            }
          catch (FaultException<MyFaultException> ex)
           {
             lblErrorMessage.Content = "Please Enter a Valid SQL Query";
            }
       }

And I wrote my GetDataTableDataCompleted event as below

     void objService_GetDataTableDataCompleted(object sender, GetDataTableDataCompletedEventArgse)
        {
         //code
        }
```

Here is my Service Method

```
 public IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> GetDataTableData(string dataBaseName, string query)
    {
        try
        {
            IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> objDictionary;
            objDictionary = objOptimityDAL.GetDataForSelectQuery(dataBaseName, query);
            return objDictionary;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MyFaultException fault = new MyFaultException();
            fault.Reason = ex.Message.ToString();
            throw new FaultException<MyFaultException>(fault, new FaultReason("Incorrect SQL Query"));

        }
    }
```

Here My WCf Service is interacting with Data Access Layer and throwing the Fault Exception Successfully but it is not  receiving  to my client Method, Instead I am getting an unhandled Exception like
 "Communication Exception was unhandled by User, the remote server returned an Error:NotFound"  in References.cs code shown below

```
 public System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>> EndGetDataTableData(System.IAsyncResult result) {
            object[] _args = new object[0];
            System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>> _result = ((System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>>)(base.EndInvoke("GetDataTableData", _args, result)));
            return _result;
        }
```

Here is the Web.config of Wcf Service

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>   
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>        
        <behavior>         
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
           <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>  
</configuration>
```

Below is my ServiceReferences.ClientConfig file

```
 <configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          closeTimeout="01:00:00"
          receiveTimeout="01:00:00"
          sendTimeout="01:00:00">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:3132/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
          name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Please Suggest me someway to catch the faultException in my SilverlightClient

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Perhaps there is some error in the configuration since you get Communication Exception. Does the service get the clients call? It sounds like you get an error when you try to invoke the service? Perhaps post your web.configs and full stack trace?

Comment: Hi Jocke, thanks for your reply, I have Edited my post with the Config files, and I am able to invoke the service method successfully , which inturn throwing an exception, but here the issue is in catching that thrown exception from the service.

Comment: Have you do a [FaultContract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.faultcontractattribute(v=vs.95).aspx) `[FaultContract(typeof(MyFaultException))]` ? [You can read this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844556(v=vs.95).aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have chosen Silverlight Enabled WCF Service when you created your service first time. It would have created all the infrastructure for you.

But you can still add the necessary code manually to the WCF Service project.

**SilverlightFaultBehavior.cs**

```
/// <summary>
/// The behavior which enables FaultExceptions for Silverlight clients
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public sealed class SilverlightFaultBehaviorAttribute : Attribute, IServiceBehavior
{
    private class SilverlightFaultEndpointBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
    {
        public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
        {
            endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new SilverlightFaultMessageInspector());
        }

        public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {
        }

        private class SilverlightFaultMessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
        {
            public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
            {
                return null;
            }

            public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
            {
                if ((reply != null) && reply.IsFault)
                {
                    HttpResponseMessageProperty property = new HttpResponseMessageProperty();
                    property.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
                    reply.Properties[HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name] = property;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        foreach (ServiceEndpoint endpoint in serviceDescription.Endpoints)
        {
            endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new SilverlightFaultEndpointBehavior());
        }
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
    }
}
```

**Service1.cs**

```
[SilverlightFaultBehaviorAttribute]
public class Service1 : IService1
{
...
}
```

And on the client you should check the `e.Error` property inside the callback function. Try/catch from your example will not work.

**The Silverlight Client**

```
objService.GetDataTableDataCompleted += (s, e) => 
    {
        if(e.Error != null) {
            if (e.Error is FaultException) {
                lblErrorMessage.Content = "Please Enter a Valid SQL Query";
            }
            // do something with other errors
        }
        else {
            // success
        }
    };

objService.GetDataTableDataAsync(_DATABASEName, strQuery);
```

Comment: I am calling objService.GetDataTableDataCompleted  event in a button click event . so what are (s, e) parameters in silverlightclient of your answer, how can i write this in my button click event. could you please be elobrate. I have edited my post silverlightclient(.xaml.cs), could you please go through that and edit your silverlightClient answer please.

Comment: @Sudhakar Byna (s,e) are input parameters of the lambda expression. You can read about lambda expressions here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Comment: Thank You. This time I am Getting an Unhandled Exception like "An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll but was not handled in user code" in my Service Method while Throwing the Fault Exception like               

throw new FaultException<MyFaultException>(fault, new FaultReason("Incorrect SQL Query"));

Comment: Then that unhandled Exception is Breaking in References.cs file at the below code
 public System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>[] EndGetSelectQueryData(System.IAsyncResult result) {
                object[] _args = new object[0];
                System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>[] _result = ((System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>[])(base.EndInvoke("GetSelectQueryData", _args, result)));
                return _result;
            }

Comment: @SudhakarByna The Visual Studio debugger stops each time an exception occurs. Just press F5 or the Continue button after it happens.